# In Windows 10, when you minimize a window, how do you keep it active?

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, alt-tab, windows-key

When I minimize a window, Windows 10 automatically cycles to the last opened program. I would like the focus to stay on window I've just minimized.

I know it is possible to press "**WinKey+Down**" to minimize a window. While keeping the "**Down Arrow**" Key pressed, the focus stays on the currently minimized window. When you let go, Windows 10 cycles to another program. It is not quite what I'm looking to for.

I've tried using "**Alt+Shift+Esc**", to cycle back to the window I just minimized. Most of the time this does not work because Windows 10 cycles to the last opened program, not the last active window (the one I just minimized).

"**Alt+Tab**" does not work also because that reopens the window (the window does not stay minimized)

Is there a registry that I can add or edit, that would keep the focus on the minimized window? Or anything else that would accomplish this? Any ideas?

Thanks, Cheers!

Comment: They mean, the program you have minimized, if it has had something happen that needs user input, will flash its logo on your taskbar.

Answer (score 1):

A minimized program in Windows cannot keep the focus. It will just flash on the
taskbar if it demands it.

If the program wants the focus, meaning that it sets the focus to itself via an
API call, its taskbar entry will flash, giving the user the option of un-minimizing it.
However, it cannot set itself up as front window, by design.

An application taking over the focus is called
[Focus stealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focus_stealing),
which was a major problem in previous versions of Windows, so safeguards were added
against it.

To show how big was this problem (and sometimes still is when programmers
find new ways of doing that), see that the Google query
[applications stealing focus](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&hl=en&source=hp&biw=&bih=&q=applications+stealing+focus&btnG=Google+Search&gbv=1)
currently gives approximately 21,400,000 results.